# how to configure AWS access key id and secret access key variables from javascript code using Pulumi automation api

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, pulumi

Hey everyone I am using Pulumi and am currently playing around with the Pulumi Automation Api. I have there inlineProgram JavaScript example here from https://github.com/pulumi/automation-api-examples/tree/main/nodejs/inlineProgram-js

everything works correctly when running

```js
node index.js
```

&

```js
node index.js destroy
```

however only once I first export my AWS env variables with a bash command or into my Linux terminal

```bash
export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID='xxx' &&
export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY='xxx' &&
export AWS_REGION='us-west-1'
```

Now the running `node index.js` works as expected.

My question is how do i eliminate the need to run this bash script and accomplish the same from within the node.js code...

I can see from the examples **index.js** file where I can do this for the AWS region

```js
...
await stack.setConfig("aws:region", { value: "us-west-1" });
```

but after several attempts have not been able to make the same happen for the AWS access key id and the AWS secret access key variables that are required...

without first running the bash script i am seeing this error from the pulumi web app interface

```
Changes:
 
    Type                 Name            Status   Info
+   pulumi:pulumi:Stack  inlineNode-dev  created  
 
Diagnostics:
  aws:s3:Bucket (s3-website-bucket)
    error: unable to discover AWS AccessKeyID and/or SecretAccessKey - see https://pulumi.io/install/aws.html for details on configuration
 
Resources:
    + created 1
 
Duration: 8s
```

i have tried quite a few different ways

```js
await stack.setConfig("aws:secretKey", { value: 'xxx' });
await stack.setConfig("aws:accessKey", { value: 'xxx' });
await stack.setConfig("aws-native:secretKey", { value: 'xxx' });
await stack.setConfig("aws-native:accessKey", { value: 'xxx' });
await stack.setConfig("aws-native:region", { value: 'xxx' });
```

and I have not been able to get it to work :/

Any help on where I am messing this up would be greatly appreciated!

Here is the full index.js file from the example

```js
const auto = require("@pulumi/pulumi/automation");
const aws = require("@pulumi/aws");
const process = require('process');

const args = process.argv.slice(2);
let destroy = false;
if (args.length > 0 && args[0]) {
    destroy = args[0] === "destroy";
}

const run = async () => {
    // This is our pulumi program in "inline function" form
    const pulumiProgram = async () => {
        // Create a bucket and expose a website index document
        const siteBucket = new aws.s3.Bucket("s3-website-bucket", {
            website: {
                indexDocument: "index.html",
            },
        });
        const indexContent = `<html><head>
<title>Hello S3</title><meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<body><p>Hello, world!</p><p>Made with ❤️ with <a href="https://pulumi.com">Pulumi</a></p>
</body></html>
`
        // write our index.html into the site bucket
        let object = new aws.s3.BucketObject("index", {
            bucket: siteBucket,
            content: indexContent,
            contentType: "text/html; charset=utf-8",
            key: "index.html"
        });

        // Create an S3 Bucket Policy to allow public read of all objects in bucket
        function publicReadPolicyForBucket(bucketName) {
            return {
                Version: "2012-10-17",
                Statement: [{
                    Effect: "Allow",
                    Principal: "*",
                    Action: [
                        "s3:GetObject"
                    ],
                    Resource: [
                        `arn:aws:s3:::${bucketName}/*` // policy refers to bucket name explicitly
                    ]
                }]
            };
        }

        // Set the access policy for the bucket so all objects are readable
        let bucketPolicy = new aws.s3.BucketPolicy("bucketPolicy", {
            bucket: siteBucket.bucket, // refer to the bucket created earlier
            policy: siteBucket.bucket.apply(publicReadPolicyForBucket) // use output property `siteBucket.bucket`
        });

        return {
            websiteUrl: siteBucket.websiteEndpoint,
        };
    };

    // Create our stack 
    const args = {
        stackName: "dev",
        projectName: "inlineNode",
        program: pulumiProgram
    };

    // create (or select if one already exists) a stack that uses our inline program
    const stack = await auto.LocalWorkspace.createOrSelectStack(args);

    console.info("successfully initialized stack");
    console.info("installing plugins...");
    await stack.workspace.installPlugin("aws", "v4.0.0");
    console.info("plugins installed");
    console.info("setting up config");
    await stack.setConfig("aws:region", { value: "us-west-1" });
    console.info("config set");
    console.info("refreshing stack...");
    await stack.refresh({ onOutput: console.info });
    console.info("refresh complete");

    if (destroy) {
        console.info("destroying stack...");
        await stack.destroy({ onOutput: console.info });
        console.info("stack destroy complete");
        process.exit(0);
    }

    console.info("updating stack...");
    const upRes = await stack.up({ onOutput: console.info });
    console.info(`update summary: \n${JSON.stringify(upRes.summary.resourceChanges, null, 4)}`);
    console.info(`website url: ${upRes.outputs.websiteUrl.value}`);
};

run().catch(err => console.log(err));
```

Comment: I just tried adding these config values myself and it worked first time.
await stack.setConfig("aws:region", { value: "us-west-1" });
    await stack.setConfig("aws:accessKey", { value: "example"});
    await stack.setConfig("aws:secretKey", { value: "bar"});

Comment: Hey thanks for the quick reply @jaxxstorm! I restarted my computer and gave it another shot with your example and sure enough it worked!